# Why is Jquery click function requiring 2 clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm clicking a button to fill a hidden value to use with php. This jQuery is making me click the button twice before it enters the value into the hidden field how do I make it only one click?

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.btn-group button').click(function(){

        $("#hidd").val( $(".btn-group").find('.active').val());

    });

});
```

html

```
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="150">150</button> 
        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="450">450</button>
    </div>  
    <input type="hidden" id="hidd" name="pass_amount" value=""></input>
```

Comment: There is no class active here.

Comment: There must be some other script to set the 'active' class to one of the buttons. Do you have more code for us?

Comment: active class gets added when button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line :

```
$("#hidd").val( $(".btn-group").find('.active').val());
```

by this one :

```
$("#hidd").val( $(this).val());
```

Because the first click make the button active , then the second one retrieves the value of the previous activated one.

Comment: Thank you. Great answer. Accepted because you explained why what I was doing was wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery's [.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) with the [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) API.

This way you target the specific button that's clicked and you can grab that buttons value with `this.value` Simple!

To target if the button (that's clicked) has the class active you can use JQuery's [.hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) API.

This snippet uses ASI ([Automatic Semicolon Inversion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsfbh17Ax9I)).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-group button').on('click', function() {
    $("#hidd").val( this.value )
    /*
      To target just the class active you can do...
      if ($(this).hasClass('active') {
        $("#hidd").val( this.value )
      }
    */
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="150">150</button> 
  <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="450">450</button>
</div>  
<input type="value" id="hidd" name="pass_amount" value="" />
```